# Restricting the content of a table

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, access-control

Im trying hard to find a way to restrict the access of a user to a particular table. Im working with views now but i cant create what i want...and i dont know if its possible.

Now, what it accomplish was to limit all access to a table..and create a view with the content the user should be able to see...but its not what a want, really.

What i was think:

When i logon with the user XXX, it should be able to visualize the database X_DB...and the table X_TABLE...
BUT when this user selects this table..he only will see the content i defined previously...not the entire content of the table.

I was able to select it into a view..but im cannot make all of it part of one process...

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: How do you want to manage access control?  Are all of your users in a corporate domain?  Is this application exposed to the Internet?  These details are important.

Comment: Im managing SQL logins, i have authority to define everything on the sql server, im able to create users..the application is not exposed to the internet

Comment: its a standart sql server.... server\instance...with users defined..

Comment: Are you trying to restrict access to specific columns (fields) of the table, or specific rows of the table, or both?

Comment: both...i have different databases with almost the same content..for different clientes...my idea was to create just one DB and give each client a password to see what he is suposed to see..got it? i have 20 dbs..with the same structures..same tables..the content just change a little

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have 20 databases, one per each client, add your client as a user to just the database you want them to access.

If you want to consolidate all of your databses to a single database, then I suggest that you add  "Client" table containing clientId (primary key) and clientName fields, and then modifying the rest of your schema by adding foreign key fields and relationships so that the other data is related to the proper client.  Then you can easily provide access to data to clients based on their clientId in conjunction with views and stored procedures.

Comment: But i want to reduce the number of Dbs...all the clients will access the same database..but view different things..its what i want to accomplish